# Logging file access in Android

Tags: android, security, logging

I'm having trobule trying to create a custom file access logger for Android. I've check [FileObsever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) but I need to get the PID (USERID would be useful also) of the process that had access to a certain list of files.

I've also tried different options but with no success.

Is is possible to log with PID accessed certain file?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

There's been some discussion of adding PID reporting to the Linux inotify() mechanism (which is what FileObserver is presumably based on), but I'm not finding out from initial searches if that was actually merged and thus inherited by Android - and if it was, it would likely only work for foreign UID's for a monitor with administrative privileges.

You could try the FileObserver and then immitate lsof by scanning through /proc for fd's, to whatever (limited?) extent you'd be allowed to do so on Android.  This would however give you race condition issues - the file could be closed again before you saw "who done it".

Likely if you really want to do this, you'll need a custom ROM - you could apply any necessary patches to inotify and either bless your security app with permissions or (if you prefer to be that way) disable the permission checks on reporting.

What I found about the patch - current merge status unknown:

http://lwn.net/Articles/307536/

Intro to direct use of inotify() (without the PID reporting):

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478?page=0,0